# Utilizing Spatial Index - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, gis, geospatial, spatial

I have a table `Points` with `shape` column for points of `geography` type, and a spatial index on the column to improve performance..

```
CREATE TABLE  Points(id VARCHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY, shape geography);
CREATE SPATIAL INDEX SIndx_Points_shape ON Points(shape);
```

I am trying to retrieve all intersecting pairs of points from the Points table with polygon shapes from `shape` column of type `geometry` in another table named `Grids`. Grids table also has a spatial index to optimize spatial queries.

```
INSERT INTO Intersections(point_id ,grid_id )
SELECT P.id , G.id
FROM Points P
INNER JOIN Grids G
ON G.SHAPE.STIntersects(geometry::STGeomFromWKB(P.shape.STAsBinary(),4326)) = 1
```

However, the execution plan indicates a Clustered Index seek on the Grids table, but it doesn't seem to use the spatial index on the Points table, which might affect query performance.

I attempted to use a query hint to specify the index, like this:

```
OPTION (TABLE HINT(P, INDEX (SIndx_Points_shape )))
```

but it throws an error

> Query processor could not produce a query plan because of the hints defined in this query. Resubmit the query without specifying any hints and without using SET FORCEPLAN.

Any ideas on why the query optimizer does not use the spatial index on the Points table and how to ensure that the optimizer utilizes the index for better performance.

Update:

- Tried using Points table with shape column of type geometry and compare directly so that the types are compatible. Produced same exact execution plan and time, with Clustered Index seek on the Grids table only

```
SELECT P.id , G.id
FROM Points P
INNER JOIN Grids G
ON G.SHAPE.STIntersects(P.shape) = 1
```

- Attempted an index hint on Points table column, Execution plan now only does Clustered Index seek on Points table replacing Grids table index.
- Attempted an index hint on both indices, it throws same error.

```
OPTION (TABLE HINT (G, INDEX(S7434_idx)), TABLE HINT (P, INDEX(SIndx_Points_shape)))
```

spatial index on Grids table

```
CREATE SPATIAL INDEX [S7434_idx] ON Grids ( [SHAPE] )USING GEOMETRY_AUTO_GRID WITH (BOUNDING_BOX =(-120.005720158, 25.837266505, -92.408500871, 49.00098643), CELLS_PER_OBJECT = 8, PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
```

--

Comment: What is the `CREATE TABLE` and `CREATE SPATIAL INDEX` for `Grids`?

Comment: Grids is a source table I did not create it, but this is the spatial index generated CREATE script

```
CREATE SPATIAL INDEX [S7434_idx] ON Grids
(
 [SHAPE]
)USING  GEOMETRY_AUTO_GRID 
WITH (BOUNDING_BOX =(-120.005720158, 25.837266505, -92.408500871, 49.00098643), 
CELLS_PER_OBJECT = 8, PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Comment: DB Fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/0iq1wDvy - I've not used spatial indexes but I imagine the fact that the reference to `[P].[shape]` is wrapped in a function isn't helping

Comment: To be comparable ([for index purposes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/spatial/spatial-indexes-overview?view=sql-server-ver16#geography)) the two references need to be persisted values with the same SRID. As Martin Smith mentioned, wrapping one of the references in a function probably isn't helping. Transforming geography to geometry with `geometry::STGeomFromWKB()` almost certainly isn't helping.

Comment: Tried writing the points to the table as geometry type and compare directly, but I got the exact same execution plan and time. Also, removed the function wrapping but no effect

Comment: So after reading your question and comments again, just to confirm here... one column is `geometry` (a planar type) and the other is `geography` (an ellispoidal type)? Consider [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76831384/edit) your `Grids.SHAPE` index into the question so that other people can see it easily and don't have to find it in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/spatial/spatial-indexes-overview?view=sql-server-ver16#queries-that-use-spatial-indexes)

> Spatial indexes are only supported in queries that include an indexed spatial operator in the WHERE clause.

Your query is only using the spatial data types in a JOIN, not in a WHERE.

Comment: It works with ON for geometry types
From documentation:
"these methods must be used within the WHERE or JOIN ON clause of a query"
It works on a join and shows in the execution plan, the problem is that it utilizes only the spatial index on the polygons and not the points. I thought it could utilize both that's why I tried writing a table with points as geometry and a spatial index on it